# В чём отличие создания web-приложения и REST-api для бэкенда?

Tags: java, spring, rest, терминология, webapi

Начинаю путь Джуна, осваиваю Java и Spring. Выполнял тестовое задание по написанию REST-api. Всё понятно - есть запросы, которые можем обрабатывать, данные шлём в каком-нибудь формате типа JSON.
Сейчас получил тестовое от другой компании - написать бэкенд web-приложения. В чём разница? Есть ли какие-то концептуальные отличия? Что нужно иметь в виду?
Просто как мне сейчас кажется, это всё те же api, с точки зрения бэкенда.

Comment: Всё верно понимаете - разницы никакой.

Comment: Проектирование и создание API считается задачей для джуна? O_o... простите за комментарий, не в полной мере относящийся к сути вопроса.

Comment: @kami, мне уже второй раз в качестве тестового задания для джуна дают написание APIs.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, то есть даже никаких особенностей, характерных для именно приложений? Типа какой-нибудь обязательной асинхронности, моментов с кешированием или ещё чего-то?
Столько гуглил уже. Границы размыты с точки зрения пользователей - это-то ладно. Что сайты статичны более, а приложения - интерактивны, и так далее. А что касается разработки - как-то не уточнялось.

Comment: Всё очень условно, единого мнения нет, какого-то международного общепризнанного документа с определениями тоже нет. В связи с этим лучше у дающего задание прямо спросить что именно он имеет в виду под теми словами, которые он произносит)

Comment: А бэкенд дали для написания API?

Comment: @RomanC, как бы да, но не совсем. Туда затолкали ещё и требования ко фронту, типа вывода в виде таблиц, подтверждения удаления и пр. Бэкенд дали для написания "веб-приложения". Это и смутило. Если было бы написано просто "напишите rest-api" - было бы всё понятно

Comment: Так да или нет, если да, то опишите бэкенд. У фронтенда свой API, ничего общего.

Comment: Всем спасибо за комментарии-мысли-советы! Ещё раз связался с hr-ом, обсудили тестовое. Договорились, что я делаю лишь бэкенд-часть. То есть по сути, действительно, разницы между rest-api и web-api нет с технической точки зрения. Разница получается в степени интерактивности интерфейса что ли.. И то такая тонкая грань.